# Update MySQL using HTML Form and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, sql-update

I've been looking through dozens of threads on here about this but have yet to find a solution.

I've created a form that is supposed to show database table contents in input boxes, and when the content of the input boxes are changed and submitted the database is supposed to update.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$dbhost = '****';
$dbuser = '****';
$dbpass = '****';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('****');

$query = "SELECT * FROM anstalld";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

$namn = $row['namn'];
$mandag = $row['mandag'];
$tisdag = $row['tisdag'];
$onsdag = $row['onsdag'];
$torsdag = $row['torsdag'];
$fredag = $row['fredag'];
?>


<td width="100"></td>
<td><?=$namn?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Mandag</td>
<td><input name="mandagid" type="text" value="<?=$mandag?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Tisdag</td>
<td><input name="tisdagid" type="text" value="<?=$tisdag?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Onsdag</td>
<td><input name="onsdagid" type="text" value="<?=$onsdag?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Torsdag</td>
<td><input name="torsdagid" type="text" value="<?=$torsdag?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Fredag</td>
<td><input name="fredagid" type="text" value="<?=$fredag?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

$namn = $_POST['namnid'];
$mandag = $_POST['mandagid'];
$tisdag = $_POST['tisdagid'];
$onsdag = $_POST['onsdagid'];
$torsdag = $_POST['torsdagid'];
$fredag = $_POST['fredagid'];

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn'");

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

The forms show the content of the database fine, but upon updating I get this message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: This can't work this way because you have multi forms with always the same `name`s for input fields. Also you are missing to put `namn` in an at least hidden field. And you missed a lot of closing `}`

Comment: @djot Thanks for pointing the multi forms thing out! How would I go about pointing the UPDATE query to the input boxes without using static names?

Comment: @user2052849 You could use an array instead: e.g. `name="fredagid[]"`. You then could loop through `$_POST` and will have several "fridays" (as many as rows hopefully). `var_dump($_POST)` then to see what I mean. Hope, your SQL will be as secure as the "anstalld" - currently it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

Use  mysqli instead of mysql, and you need to pass the database name or schema:

before:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

after:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $myDBname);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It did however not fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: try close the connection to end of code, put this: `mysql_close($conn);`

Comment: everytime, when you open a connection, after use, you need to close the connection

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to make any difference though :/

Comment: the user of mysql check if this have permission to execute UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

Update query may have some issues

```
$query = "UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn' ";
echo $query;
```

Please make sure that, your variable not having values with qoutes ( ' ), May be the query is breaking somewhere.

echo the query and try to execute in phpmyadmin itself. Then you can find the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have already executed your query here

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn'");
```

So this line has the problem

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); //$sql is not a query its a result set here
```

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn'";    
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); //execute your query
```

> As a sidenote: MySQL_* extension is deprecated use MySQLi_* or PDO
>   instead.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the "You have an error in your SQL syntax" msg, however, my DB is still not being updated with the newly added content.

Comment: Your db is not being updated because you are generating your input box in a loop which will create many input elements with same name. You can try by changing the name of the input fields to an array like this `<input name="mandagid[]" type="text" value="<?=$mandag?>">`. You need to do this for every input element and process accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is incorrect.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE anstalld....
```

only

```
$sql = "UPDATE anstalld...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in your sql syntax.

please use this query and checkout.

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE `anstalld` SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. Put the table name in quotes (``).
beside put variable '".$xyz."'.

So your sql query will be like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `anstalld` SET mandag = "'.$mandag.'" WHERE namn =".$name)or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it is. I'm working with this code only. Still how? can you point out the mistake so. I can improve

Comment: You have a problem with quotes, the first string is "UPDATE `anstalld` SET mandag = " the next one is '.$mandag.', you would get a parse error because there is no . between them. If you fix all your mistakes, your code will become the same as one of 0 point answers below

Comment: can you write the entire query for me? Actually, I didn't get what you are saying. @Naktibalda

Answer (score 0):

First of all use 
    `mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)`

Second - put `mysqli_` everywhere instead of `mysql_`

Third - use this
    `$sql = "UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '.$mandag.', tisdag = '.$tisdag.', onsdag = '.$onsdag.', torsdag = '.$torsdag.', fredag = '.$fredag.' WHERE namn = '.$namn.'";

$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ); //execute your query`

if Your data is being updated in your database but not in your table its because when you will click on update button, the request is made to the same file.
It first selects the data from the database when it is not updated prints it in the table and then update it according to the flow. If you have to update it as you click on update button then put this section

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

$namn = $_POST['namnid'];
$mandag = $_POST['mandagid'];
$tisdag = $_POST['tisdagid'];
$onsdag = $_POST['onsdagid'];
$torsdag = $_POST['torsdagid'];
$fredag = $_POST['fredagid'];

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE anstalld SET mandag = '$mandag', tisdag = '$tisdag', onsdag = '$onsdag', torsdag = '$torsdag', fredag = '$fredag' WHERE namn = '$namn'");

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}


?>`
```

after connecting with database.

Answer (score -1):

First example does not require the accumulative kind of ordering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).